# Can't make Notifications appear on Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working on a messaging app, I want to create a notification every time a friend sends a message, Everything seems correct but the notifications still won't show up. Here's my code.

```
public void createNotify(String name, String content, int id, Bitmap icon, boolean isGroup) {
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String NC_ID = "NOTIFY";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NC_ID, "New Message", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription(content);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NC_ID)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000})
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        if (isGroup) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_group);
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_person);
        }


        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

There is too much of similar questions on similar problem on Stack Overflow, and I tried most of them that were answered but not to avail. Most of the questions had `setSmallIcon()` problem but for me this is not the case. I checked the documentations as well. Can anyone highlight the problem?
Everything seems fine to me but it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, putting `setSmallIcon` is necessary

second, you haven't chosen a channel for your notification. use this:

```
notificationBuilder.setChannel(channelId)
```

Comment: But I am already passing channel ID to `NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NC_ID)` which already satisfies need for `notificationBuilder.setChannel(channelId)` and as for `setSmallIcon` it is already set.

Comment: @SalmanMalik It's wired because I tested your code and the notification appeared for me! what is the android version of your device that is running the app? I must say that the way you made the notification, it might only work for android o and above. because on creating the notification, you passed the channel into the constructor and only android o and above use channels. the only thing I changed was that I removed large Icon but i don't think that was the problem.

Comment: I am testing it on Android O, can you tell me how can I make it work on Below android O? because I did not happen to notice it.

Comment: @SalmanMalik you can create two types of notifications. one with the channel and one without it. you can go and say, if the version of android was o and above, build this notification with this channel. otherwise create a notification without channel and at the end notify it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the notification code and you should check other parts of your code.

Comment: I got this, I tried running code without function call. It is working indeed. I am somehow failing to trigger it correctly. I really need to look into my code.